# Fetching bccAddress from Messaging.inboundEmail

Tags: apex-email-service

We are using Email Service and its handler class creates custom record in Salesforce based on its content. Please let me know if there is any possibility to capture the bcc address from Messaging.inboundEmail? I checked the documentation but there is no mention of accessing bcc address though accessing ccaddresses is available.

Answer (score 0):

> The primary reason people send blind carbon copies (BCC) is to mask the
>   other recipients from the list of recipients.If the sender bcc'd
>   multiple people (by putting their addresses in the Bcc field before
>   sending), none of those recipients would see who else the email was
>   sent to.

So let it be SF email service or any email provider/sevice, noone will allow you to see the BCC email address as it would indicate a breach of privacy of sender.

Source: https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-bcc-blind-carbon-copy-1171131